# Files not added after being dropped with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm really confused as to why this is happening. I'm creating a drag and drop area for my form and so far I can drop the files and report what has been dropped. I'm then trying to append dropped files before submit then on submit send the form via ajax.

I can drop the files but they don't seem to submit with the form.

```
      // Flie Input Listener
  .on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function(e) {
    showFiles( e.target.files );
    droppedFiles = "";
    //$form.trigger( 'submit' ); // automatically submit the form on file select
  })
  .on( 'drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop', '#dropArea', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
  .on( 'dragover dragenter', '#dropArea', function() {
    $("#dropArea").addClass( 'is-dragover' );
  })
  .on( 'dragleave dragend drop', '#dropArea', function() {
    $("#dropArea").removeClass( 'is-dragover' );
  }).on( 'drop', '#dropArea', function(e) {
        droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
        showFiles( droppedFiles );  // function to replace text with file name dropped
        var $form = $('#dropArea').closest('form'); find the form the files were dropped on
        console.log($form.attr('id')); // check the form was found
        var files = new FormData($form.get(0));  // create the Form Data object to store the files
        $input = $form.find( 'input[type="file"]' ); // find the input field to attach dropped files
        console.log($input.attr('id')); // check right input item selected
        $.each( droppedFiles, function( i, file ) { // loop round all files attached
          files.append( $input.attr( 'name' ), file );
        });
        $form.trigger( 'submit' ); // auto submit form just for testing 
      })
```

Everything seems to work but the dragged and dropped files don't attach and get submitted.

Comment: figured this out i was creating a new FormData object in a separate function that was overriding this so all working. Thanks Mike for the grammar spelling corrections been up four days straight to get this project finished and running just on coffee so typing was a little sloppy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured this out i was creating a new FormData object in a separate function that was overriding this so all working. Thanks Mike for the grammar spelling corrections been up four days straight to get this project finished and running just on coffee so typing was a little sloppy